# How to add values in wp_postmeta?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working in wordpress.I have to add some fields to the my post and I want the added information of my post to be added in serailized form in metavalue in wp_postmeta.How can I do this?
I have found a page `post.php` that seem to handle this.But I just cannot seem to find anything that would let me add the values of my field to the postmeta.
HELP

Updated:
I have also seen `add_post_meta` Does this add the value into the database or just the adds the key and the value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom fields while adding new post to add new values in wp_postmeta.

Click on add new post and search for custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_post_meta` method to get a specific field or `get_post_custom()` to get them all.

But in this case i guess you ought to use `the_meta();` that will get you the current post meta. once you add a custom field inside the post/page and put this in the template.

Learn how to use it [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_meta)